# Rails Route Error - route for new does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to make a rails 4 app.

I have a projects model and a project_questions model.

Project questions belongs to projects.

I have made a project questions form which users can use to ask a question about a project.

My trouble is, when I press submit, the route error appears saying there is no matching route. I don't understand that because I made the model through scaffolding which I understood made the main routes automatically.

My structure is:

Project_question form (using simple form gem):

```
  <%= simple_form_for :project_questions do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :project_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: @project_question_id} %>
          <%= f.input :title, label: 'Question:',  :label_html => {:class => 'question-title'}, placeholder: 'Type your question here', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 4, class: 'response-project'} %>
          <%= f.input :content, label: 'Is there any context or other information?', :label_html => {:class => 'question-title'}, placeholder: 'Context might help to answer your question', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 5, class: 'response-project'} %>

      <br><br><br>
          <%= f.button :submit, 'Send!', :class => "cpb" %>

<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :project_questions do
      resources :project_answers
    end
  end
```

Controller for project question:

```
class ProjectQuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /project_questions
  # GET /project_questions.json
  def index
    @project_questions = ProjectQuestion.all
  end

  # GET /project_questions/1
  # GET /project_questions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /project_questions/new
  def new
    @project_question = ProjectQuestion.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    # @project_id = params[:project_id]
    @project_question.project_answers[0] = ProjectAnswer.new

  end

  # GET /project_questions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /project_questions
  # POST /project_questions.json
  def create
    @project_question = ProjectQuestion.new(project_question_params)
    @project_question.project_id = project_question_params[:project_id]


    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project_question, notice: 'Project question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project_question }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project_question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /project_questions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /project_questions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_question.update(project_question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project_question, notice: 'Project question was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project_question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /project_questions/1
  # DELETE /project_questions/1.json
  def destroy
    @project_question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_questions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project_question
      @project_question = ProjectQuestion.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_question_params
      params[:project_question].permit(:id, :title, :content, :project_id, :user_id,
      project_answer_atttibutes: [:id, :answer, :project_question_id, :user_id]
      )
    end
end
```

Controller for project:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  #layout :projects_student_layout

  before_action :authenticate_user!  

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects


    #can i have more than one index? do i need to change something in the routes? if i want to list the related projects and the expiring projects - how do i do that within one index?

    #is there a way to order these, so that for educators they are in order of course and for students they are in order of next milestone date?
    #@projects.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # def index2
 #    @projects = Project.find_xxx_xx
 #  end

  def list
    @projects = Project.find(:all)
  end

  def toggle_draft
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.draft = true
    @project.save
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
    #authorise @project

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @creator = User.find(@project.creator_id)
    @creator_profile = @creator.profile

    #@approver_profile = User.find(@project.educator_id).profile #educators are the only people who approve projects
#    if profile == 'studnet'
    #@approval = @project.approval

 #   @invitations = @project.project_invitations

  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    #authorise @project
    @project = Project.new
    @project.scope = Scope.new
    @project.scope.datum = Datum.new
    @project.scope.material = Material.new
    @project.scope.mentoring = Mentoring.new
    @project.scope.participant = Participant.new
    @project.scope.funding = Funding.new
    @project.scope.ethic = Ethic.new
    @project.scope.group_research = GroupResearch.new
    @project.scope.backgroundip = Backgroundip.new
    @project.scope.result = Result.new
    @project.scope.finalise = Finalise.new

  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    #authorise @project
    @project =Project.find(params[:id])    
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    #authorise @project
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.creator_id = current_user.id
    @project.users << current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    #authorise @project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.creator_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    #authorise @project

    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(
      :id, :title, :description, :video_proposal, :link_to_video_proposal,
      :expiry_date_for_sponsor_interest,  :motivation, :approach,
      :completion_date, :start_date, :industry_id,  :recurring_project,
      :frequency, :date_for_student_invitation, :date_for_student_interest, :closed, :student_objective, 
      :industry_relevance, :hero_image, :project_id,
      project_question_attributes: [:title, :content, :user_id, :project_id,
      project_answer_attributes: [:answer, :project_question_id]],
      scope_attributes: [:id, :project_id, :data, :material, :mentoring, :participant, :funding, :ethic, :group, :result, :disclosure, :finalise,
                         :if_mentoring, :if_participant, :if_funding, :if_ethic, :if_group_research, :if_backgroundip, :if_datum, :if_material,
                         datum_attributes: [:id, :prim_sec, :qual_quant, :survey, :survey_link, :experiment, :other_type, :other_description,
                                           :confidential, :data_description, :scope_id],
                         material_attributes: [:id, :mattype, :description, :scope_id],
                         mentoring_attributes: [:id, :frequency, :description, :scope_id],
                         funding_attributes: [:id,  :expenses, :honorarium, :financing, :currency, :size, :amount_expenses, :amount_honorarium,
                                 :comment, :amount_principal_financing, :return_on_finance, :period_of_return, :expense_description, :amount_expenses_pennies, :amount_honorarium_pennies, :amount_principal_financing_pennies,
                                               :amount_expenses_currency, :scope_id],
                         participant_attributes: [:id,  :title, :description, :location, :costs, :participation_cost,
                                                   :eligibility, :eligibility_criteria, :currency, :participation_cost_pennies, :participation_cost_currency,
                                                   :location_specific ],
                         group_research_attributes: [:id, :number_of_group_members, :scope_id],
                         ethic_attributes: [:id, :obtained, :date_expected, :ethics_comment, :ethics_policy_link, :scope_id],
                         result_attributes: [:id, :report, :standard_licence, :bespoke_licence, :option, :assignment, :other_outcome,
                                             :consulting, :link_to_bespoke_licence, :description],
                         disclosure_attributes: [:id, :allusers, :publicity, :limitedorganisation, :limitedindustry, :limiteduser, :approveddisclosure],
                         backgroundip_attributes: [:id, :scope_id, :copyright, :design, :patent, :trademark, :geographical_indication,
                                                   :trade_secret, :other, :identifier_copyright, :identifier_design, :identifier_patent,
                                                   :identifier_trademark, :identifier_geographical_indication, :identifier_trade_secret,
                                                   :identifier_other, :description, :registered_owner, :unregistered_interest, :conditions,
                                                   :pbr, :identifier_pbr ],

                         finalise_attributes: [:id, :draft, :reminder, :reminder_date, :finalised_at, :scope_id]
                          ]
      )


    end
```

The error message says:

```
No route matches [POST] "/projects/70/project_questions/new"
```

I don't know where to make a route or how to make a route for new. I thought that was part of the automated process when you generate scaffolding. Can anyone see what has gone wrong?

I found another user on SO who has problems with nested routes. They changed their controller show action as follows:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:id])
  @photo = @album.photos.build
end
```

At the moment, my show action in project questions is empty. However, it belongs to projects which I thought would cover it. Is there a series of steps to follow to make a nested controller work?

Thank you

Comment: On clicking on which link you get that error?

Comment: Use `<%= simple_form_for @project_question do |f| %>` instead of `<%= simple_form_for :project_questions do |f| %>`

Comment: Are you sure that you are not changing any code from scaffolding? It seems there is a mistake in <%= simple_form_for :project_questions do |f| %> it should be <%= simple_form_for @project_question do |f| %> or this <%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_question] do |f| %>

Comment: Do I need to make the same change in the create function of the controller?

Comment: Hi Pavan, I'll copy the code that I eventually found to make this work later today so that others can see it too. I think you sent me in the right direction for things to look for, so I'll tick your answer, but if others are reading this, please note that you might need to follow the solution that I found to solve the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No route matches [POST] "/projects/70/project_questions/new"

You have ***nested routes*** defined,so it should be like this

```
<%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_question] do |f| %>
```

Comment: `No route matches [POST] "/projects/70/project_questions/new"` Problem is his form expecting `POST` new, which should be get instead..

Comment: Hi Pavan, I tried this, thanks I didn't think of the change to the routes, but I get this error: can't write unknown attribute `builder'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your route.rb file its in your form. You didn't correctly pointed to your to where it should go.

Change your form to below.

```
<%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_question] do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :project_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: @project_question_id} %>
          <%= f.input :title, label: 'Question:',  :label_html => {:class => 'question-title'}, placeholder: 'Type your question here', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 4, class: 'response-project'} %>
          <%= f.input :content, label: 'Is there any context or other information?', :label_html => {:class => 'question-title'}, placeholder: 'Context might help to answer your question', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 5, class: 'response-project'} %>

      <br><br><br>
          <%= f.button :submit, 'Send!', :class => "cpb" %>

<% end %>
```

you should pass an array to simple_form_for method as first parameter (responsible for setting the proper form URL)

Comment: When I try it this way, I get an error that says: Cannot redirect to nil! It refers me to the redirect line in my controller's create action which says:         format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project question was successfully created.' }